# Macbook not giving 5.1 Surround sound even after Audio-Midi configuration

Tags: hdmi, speakers, macbook-pro-retina, surround-sound, home-theater

I have recently bought [LG BH9540TW](http://www.lg.com/hk_en/home-theater-system/lg-BH9540TW) which is surround sound system and comes with a BluRay player. I connected my Macbook Pro to the blu-ray player via HDMI cable.

I have followed the following steps:

1. Sound Preferences ->Output tab-> Select "LG-BDHT"
2. Open Audio MIDI setup-> Choose HDMI on the left side menu->Configure Speakers
3. Choose Multichannel 5.1-> Apply

**When I test the speakers during the configuration in Audio MIDI setup by clicking one by one on the speakers, all the speakers work fine**.

***PROBLEM:*** I have tested several youtube videos ([example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eL9-sIZRDHg)), music on iTunes and other stuff but there is no sound from the rear speakers. But if I open the Audio MIDI Setup configuration again and check the speakers one by one....they work.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in many of the comments under that post, YouTube only supports Stereo.

You need to download the linked file to test.

Comment: Thanks, I also figured out that I am getting surround sound only on some downloaded videos. Is there any way (or website) where I can access surround sound videos (only to test)?